# how to run multiple nested ssh sessions using python

Tags: python, ssh, nested

my requirement is as given below:

1. ssh to jump server.
2. In a loop do the below:
   2.1. ssh to remote host
   2.2. Run a series of commands and process the o/p.
   2.3. exit the ssh session to remote host.

Below is the code snippet I wrote for the same:

```
import paramiko
import sys

ips = ['10.154.65.186','10.154.65.187','10.154.65.188','10.154.65.189','10.154.65.190']

#ssh to jump server
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.141.21.239',22, 'admin', 'admin') # ssh to jump server

# running some commands on the jump server

chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
chan.send('ifconfig\n')
buff = b''
while not buff.endswith(b'$ '):
    buff = chan.recv(9999)
    print (buff.decode(),end='')

# ssh to the remote hosts in a loop

for ip in ips:
    cmd = 'ssh user@'+ip+'\n'
    print (cmd)
    chan.send(cmd)

    buff = b''
    while not buff.endswith(b'password: '):
        buff = chan.recv(99)
        if buff.find(b"Host key verification failed") != -1 :
            while not buff.endswith(b'$ '):
                buff = chan.recv(99)
                print (buff.decode(),end='')
            cmd = 'ssh-keygen -f "/home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "'+ip+'"\n'
            chan.send (cmd)
            while not buff.endswith(b'$ '):
                buff = chan.recv(99)
                print (buff.decode(),end='')
            cmd = 'ssh user@'+ip+'\n'
            chan.send(cmd)
            while not buff.endswith(b'password: '):
                buff = chan.recv(99)
   
        chan.send('Password\n')
        buff = b''
    while not buff.endswith(b'$ '):
        buff = chan.recv(9999)

# Execute whatever commands and wait for a prompt again.
    chan.send('ls -lrt\n')
    buff = b''
    while not buff.endswith(b'$ '):
        buff = chan.recv(9999)
        print (buff.decode(),end='')
    chan.send("ifconfig -a\n")
    buff = b''
    while not buff.endswith(b'$ '):
        buff = chan.recv(9999)
        print (buff.decode(),end='')
    chan.send("exit\n")
    buff = b''
    while not buff.endswith(b'$ '):
        buff = chan.recv(9999)
        print (buff.decode(),end='')
    chan.close()

ssh.close()
```

But I see the below behavior when I execute the script:
After executing ifconfig, it tries to connect to the 1st IP from the list. but nothing happens afterwards. when I terminate the execution with ^c, below message is seen.

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 232  bytes 18786 (18.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 232  bytes 18786 (18.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

admin@jump-sftp:~$ ssh user@10.154.65.186

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Test\Python_Scripts\test2.py", line 30, in <module>
    buff = chan.recv(99)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 699, in recv
    out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\paramiko\buffered_pipe.py", line 160, in read
    self._cv.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 320, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
^C
c:\Test\Python_Scripts>
```

Can someone help me with correcting the above snipper per my requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1018#issuecomment-744151656 -- it's much easier to use sshd's built-in features for this instead of starting a remote ssh shell command.

Comment: The jump server in above question also acts as a master node and I need to run some commands on master node as well. These results are used to determine the commands to be run on the remote servers. transport method didn't work when I tried.

Comment: "Didn't work" is considerably less clear than ideal. Does `ssh -o 'JumpHost address-of-jump-host' address-of-final-host` work from the command line? (If not, that may imply that the server has the relevant features turned off; whereas if it _does_ work, that implies the configuration is fine and what you have is a code bug).

Comment: As mentioned, it is more of a master node than jump server. I have to execute some commands on the master node and based on that o/p I have to connect to different remote hosts and execute some more commands. so, the command you mentioned above is not suitable for my task. Sorry.

Comment: You can create multiple channels over a single transport, so I don't understand your objection.

Comment: Nothing stops you from creating a channel to run a command on the master node, then a new one that does the jumphost thing, _all over the same transport_ that you authenticated just once. You don't even need paramiko for that, you can do it over regular command-line openssh if you use the `ControlMaster` feature.

Comment: can you please share any sample code for this, if you have? or share any link for the same? Thanks.

Comment: Code for _what_? I mean, on the paramiko end, it's literally a matter of using the same transport object more than once, calling `exec_command()` for commands you want to run, and calling `open_channel()` explicitly when you want to have it do forwarding on your behalf. Or are you asking how to do the same thing from the Linux command line with OpenSSH?

Comment: ...for the OpenSSH command-line-usage end, a good place to start is https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing

Comment: (pretty much all the interesting code I've personally written with paramiko is owned by former employers; none of it is publicly available).

Comment: Many thanks Charles Duffy. Will look into this.